Path ambiguity in IntelliJ
I have a path in my Intellij Run/Debug Configurations "Environment variables" text as PARAMETER_PATH=C:/Users/john.locke\myFolder\parameters.ini
What I don't understand is normally this file path is C:\Users\john.locke\myFolder\parameter.ini when I right click on file  and get location.
Why is it written both forward and backward slashes in IntelliJ?

Note that Java on Windows handles both types of slash as if you used the normal Windows backslash file separator.
